# PHP ::: secure SESSION_ID ::: no CSRF?

Tags: php, session, csrf

Using this:

```
function nonce($str,$expires){
return sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i',ceil(time()/$expires)*$expires).$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$salt.$str);
}
```

Let's say I initialize my session_id after I log in, also generating a thumbprint, like this:

```
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['thumbprint']=nonce(session_id().'thumbprint',86400);
```

And call these:

```
function valid_session(){
    return ($_SESSION['thumbprint']==nonce(session_id().'thumbprint',86400));
}

function logged_in(){
    return (valid_session()&&isset($_SESSION['user']['id'])&&isset($_SESSION['user']['typeid'])&&isset($_SESSION['user']['email']));
}
```

At the top of every page:

```
if(logged_in==false){//logout & redirect back to index}
```

With a thumbprint under such scrutiny do I even need to make tokens for each function call or is this implimentation sufficient to protect against CSRF?

::: 86400 is 24 hours which I realize is a long time. Is that too long to realy on a unique ID for?
::: When I say secure functions I mean functions could be secured by using the same nonce or a token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use one-time tokens for form submissions.  `uniqid()` is sufficient for this.  Store the token in the session when you generate it, and include it in your form.  Then on your form POST processing script, check to make sure the value posted is the value in the session.

All you're doing by generating thumbprints using stuff like `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and such, is fundamentally breaking your application for people who use gateways (AOL is the canonical example).

Comment: Ok, so lets say I take out $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], and leave $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$salt.$str ... still a pretty secure nonce. But is calling logged_in() at the top of every page sufficient to protect against CSRF?... because im still checking for a unique id.

Comment: Define "secure".  Because what you're doing is completely unnecessary, and is no more secure than what I advised.  It does, however, break AJAX requests (due to using `session_regenerate_id()` on every request, leading to a race condition), forms on previous pages using the Back button (due to your nonce being `session_id()` dependent), etc.

Comment: well no the session_regenerate_id() is only used on log in, i should have made that clearer.

Comment: Well, that's good.  Session ids should only change when user privileges change.  Still, I don't see the point in including all that extra stuff in your nonce.  It doesn't increase security, and can potentially hurt usability.  [This is a good read](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries), if you haven't read it already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CSRF protect class written by Simon Willison http://simonwillison.net/static/2008/csrf_protect.php.txt

Don't forget to check his blog : http://simonwillison.net:8003/ ! Got married !

Also you may try: www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)
and the "How to Test for CSRF Vulnerabilities" section.

Have fun